# What is the error in this function that deletes all the strong numbers in a given array using RECURSION?

Tags: c, recursion

All other functions that are being used here(checkstrong and factorial) work perfectly fine.
This deletestrong function ends up deleting all the elements in the array.

```
int deletestrong(int arr[],int n,int current){
    if(current >= n){
        return n;
    }
    if(checkstrong(arr[current]==1)){
        if(current== n-1){
            n--;
        }

        else {
            for(int i=current; i< n-1 ;i++){
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            }
            n--;
        }
    }

    else{
        current++;
    }
    deletestrong(arr,n,current);
}
```

**DRIVER FUNCTION**

```
int main(){
    int n;
    int arr[20];
    printf("Enter number of elements.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the array.\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printarray(arr,n);
    n=deletestrong(arr,n,0);
    printf("After deleting all the strong numbers.\n");
    printarray(arr,n);
}
```

Comment: Where does `deletestrong` return?

Comment: my guess something wrong here: ```if(checkstrong(arr[current]==1))```. did you mean ```if (checkstrong(arr[current])==1)```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, then pay attention to them. Start by getting this code to compile cleanly.

Comment: your code is fine. your only problem is the one I pointed out

Comment: YES!. Thankyou for pointing that out.

Comment: I corrected it. The code works now!

Comment: @KamilCuk The number of elements in the array after deleting the strong numbers.

Comment: No it doesn't return the count. When `current >= n` is false, there is no return statement.

Comment: @KamilCuk if  current>= n is false then what it means is that there are still a few elements left in the array which have not been checked whether they are strong numbers or not.

Comment: But there is no `return` statement, when `current < n`, the  function does not return anything. The function only `return n` when `curent >= n`. But if it isn't, the function doesn't return.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you always send 1 or true or 0 or false to `checkstrong` method.

```
if (  checkstrong(arr[current]==1)  )
```

The value of `arr[current]==1` is always 1 or true

**Correct code:**

```
if ( checkstrong(arr[current]) == 1 )
```

**Or:**

```
if ( checkstrong(arr[current]) )
```

Comment: No, the `arr[current]` comes from the `stdin`, it can be any value.

Comment: Yes. 
i changed the content of if statement. the code works now.

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro true. updated my answer. which means it could be also 0 or false

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this line: `if (checkstrong(arr[current] == 1)) {`

I changed it to: `if (checkstrong(arr[current]) == 1) {`

I couldn't test, but think this will work:

```
int deletestrong(int arr[],int n,int current){
    if(current >= n){
        return n;
    }
    if (checkstrong(arr[current]) == 1) {
        if (current != n-1) {
            for(int i=current; i< n-1 ;i++){
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            }
        }
        n--;
    }

    else{
        current++;
    }
    return deletestrong(arr,n,current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the third parameter is redundant. The function can be written in different ways. One of approaches is when the function returns the number of elements in the array that are not strong numbers.

Your implementation of the function at least has undefined behavior because the function returns nothing when the control is passed to this statement

```
    //...
    deletestrong(arr,n,current);
}
```

This if statement

```
 if( checkstrong( arr[current] == 1 ) ){
```

has a logicak error. You mean instead

```
if( checkstrong( arr[current] ) == 1 ){
```

The function can be written the following way

```
size_t deletestrong( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t non_strong_numbers = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        if ( checkstrong( *a ) )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 1; i != n; i++ ) a[i-1] = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            non_strong_numbers = 1;
            ++a;
        }

        non_strong_numbers += deletestrong( a, n - 1 ); 
    }

    return non_strong_numbers;
}
```

And called like

```
size_t n;
int arr[20];
printf("Enter number of elements.\n");
scanf( "%zu",&n );
//...
n = deletestrong( arr, n );
//...
```

Comment: Your answser seems good and pretty explicit to me, you don't deserve a -1

Comment: There is a last flaw in that code, however, if user enters something greater than 20 -> Boom !. I would dynamically allocate memory to `arr` using `n`

Comment: @Cid What you have said has nothing common with my answer.